# How to hide cookie warnings in Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, cookies

On Chrome for desktop I use the extension "[I Don't Care About Cookies](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/i-dont-care-about-cookies/fihnjjcciajhdojfnbdddfaoknhalnja?hl=en)" to hide [cookie warnings](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPrivacy_Regulation_(European_Union)) that I personally don't care for.

I'd like to do something similar in Chrome for Android.

I've tried searching around for a way to do it, but nothing has come up so far.

I have root and Xposed Framework so I wonder if some adblocker that uses those may have some list I can add to block at least some of the most widespread templates for cookie warnings.

Or there may be some other way to do it.

My phone runs Nougat and the latest stable version of Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old thread, but posting an answer for other people's info.

I use Kiwi Browser - it's Chromium based so works just like Chrome, but unlike Chrome for Android it allows you to install Chrome desktop extensions.

Comment: Are you serious? I will try this out for sure. You will be getting a bounty if this is legit.